# Output Panel reRender issue

Tags: visualforce, rerender

VF Page Code:

```
<apex:form id="myForm" >          
    <fieldset class="slds-form--compound">  
        <div class="form-element__group">
            <div class="intro">
                <span id='mainerrorMessage' style="display:none; color:red; font-weight: bold;"></span>
                <legend class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-title--caps"><b>Filter:</b></legend>  
                <div class="slds-form-element__row slds-large-show"> 
                    <apex:outputpanel id="UpdatePanel" > 
                        <apex:outputPanel id="UpdatePanel1" rendered="{!IF(wrapList.size>0,true,false)}">
                            <div class="intro1">
                                <legend class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-title--caps"><b>Set all engagements on this page to:</b></legend>   
                                <div class="slds-form-element__row slds-large-show">
                                    <label class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--1-of-2" style="width: 49.8%;">
                                        <span class="slds-form-element__helper">SpecialtyTest:</span> 
                                        <apex:actionFunction name="check" action="{!applyGlobalchanges}" reRender="trackAssignOut,spAssignoption" status="statusSaveTrip">
                                            <apex:param name="sampleText" value="" assignTo="{!act}" />
                                        </apex:actionFunction>
                                        <apex:outputPanel >
                                            <div class="requiredInput">
                                                <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                                                <div class="picklist">
                                                    <apex:inputField value="{!Engagement__c.Track_Assignment__c}" id="check" onchange="Callmefunc('{!$Component.check}');"/>
                                                </div>                                      
                                            </div>
                                        </apex:outputPanel>  
                                        <span id='mainerrorMessage' style="display:none; color:red; font-weight: bold;"></span>
                                    </label>                       
                                </div>  
                            </div><br/>                                 
                        </apex:outputPanel>  
                    </apex:outputPanel>     
                </div> 
            </fieldset> <br/>      
            <apex:outputpanel id="studentTable1">
                <apex:outputPanel id="datePanelContainer1" rendered="{!IF(wrapList.size>0,true,false)}">
                    <div class="slds-card">                
                        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                            <div class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <div class="slds-media__figure slds-icon slds-icon-standard-contact slds-icon--small">
                                    <img src="/resource/LDS/assets/icons/standard/contact_60.png" alt="Placeholder" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-media__body">
                                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-truncate">Engagement ({!wrapList.size})  </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-card__body">
                            <table id="conTable" class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal slds-no-row-hover"  cellspacing="0">                         
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">                                
                                        <th ><b>Student Engagement</b></th>
                                        <!--<th ><b>Student Full Name</b></th>-->
                                        <th ><b>Learning Community</b></th>                                
                                        <th><b>Specialty Assignment</b></th>
                                        <th><b>Secondary Specialty Assignment</b> </th>
                                        <th><b>Specialty Interest</b></th> 
                                        <th>
                                            <apex:outputPanel id="statusTitleCheck">                                       
                                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!statusColCheck}" >
                                                    <b>Status</b>
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                            </apex:outputPanel>
                                        </th> 
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!wrapList}" var="e">
                                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">                                      
                                            <td role="gridcell" data-label="Account Name">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub"><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.name}" /></div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" value="{!e.selectedLC}" size="1" id="lcoption">
                                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedCLC}"/> 
                                                    <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/> 
                                                </apex:selectList>
                                            </td>                 

                                            <td>                                   
                                                <apex:outputPanel id="ref3" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" >
                                                    <apex:inputField value="{!e.eng.Site__c}" id="ParentPicklist"> </apex:inputfield> 
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                                <apex:outputPanel id="trackAssignOut" >
                                                    <apex:outputPanel id="trackAssignIn" > 
                                                        <div class="picklist">                                        
                                                            <apex:inputField value="{!e.eng.Track_Assignment__c}" id="spAssignoption"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </apex:outputPanel>                                      
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" value="{!e.secondspecialityAssignmnet}" size="1" id="secondAssignoption">
                                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!trackOptions}"/> 
                                                    <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/>
                                                </apex:selectList>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.Prospect_Track_Interest__c }" /></td>  
                                            <td >
                                                <apex:outputPanel id="statusCheck" rendered="{!errorCheck}">
                                                    <apex:outputPanel id="statusCheckIn" rendered="{!statusColCheck}">                
                                                        <div style="width: 150px; font-weight: bold; white-space: initial; color:{!IF(e.errorMessage =='Success','#07C81A', '#FB0707')}"> 
                                                            <apex:outputtext value="{!e.errorMessage } " />
                                                            <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </apex:outputPanel>                                      
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                            </td>                                                     
                                        </tr>  
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </tbody>                         
                            </table>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>  
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel>    
        </apex:form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Callmefunc(id) {            
    var type = document.getElementById(id).value; 
    check(type);              
}
```

VF Page Render tag:

```
<td>
    <apex:outputPanel id="trackAssignOut" >
        <apex:outputPanel id="trackAssignIn" > 
            <div class="picklist">                                        
                <apex:inputField value="{!e.eng.Track_Assignment__c}" id="spAssignoption"/>
            </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>                                      
    </apex:outputPanel>
</td>
```

**Issue:**

When I am changing the value of input field onChange event, the Output panel is not rendering, however the input field value is passing to controller properly. Only problem is rendering. Any thing I am missing here?

Comment: Please update your question with complete VF page there is no form element the code snap is not coorct

Comment: I see you have `status= statusSaveTrip`. What do you have in `<apex:actionStatus>` tag as starttext and stop content? Does the content appear?

Comment: stopText="" has nothing. It works fine for other action methods.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty: Updated the VF page with the form. I could not update entire page as character limitation.

Comment: What is the return type of applyGlobalchanges did you tried putting oncomplete on the actionFuction. If the return type is not Pagereference/void try returning Pagereference /void. also put console.log to ensure actionfunction is getting called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

I was not passing the param value to controller field properly. So I did resolve the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Engagement__c.Track_Assignment__c}" id="check" onchange="Callmefunc('{!$Component.check}');"/>
```

Try this VF Page Code:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Engagement__c.Track_Assignment__c}" id="check" onchange="Callmefunc();">
    <script>
        var checkId = '{$Component.check}';
    </script>
</apex:inputField>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function Callmefunc() {            
    var type = document.getElementById(checkId).value; 
    // if it is a checkbox use checked 
    //var type = document.getElementById(checkId).checked;
    check(type);              
}
```

Comment: I tried with your approach, actionfunction is not firing. With my approach action function is firing and value is passing to controller.